# Python process abruptly killed during execution

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, process, psycopg2

I'm new to python and am facing what seems to be a memory leakage error. 
I've written a simple script that is trying to fetch multiple columns from a postgres database and then proceeds to perform simple subtraction on these columns and store the result in a temporary variable which is being written to a file. I need to do this on multiple pairs of columns from the db and I'm using a list of lists to store the different column names.

I'm loop over the individual elements of this list until the list is exhausted. While I'm getting valid results(by valid I mean that the output file contains the expected values) for the first few column pairs, the program abruptly gets "Killed" somewhere in between execution. Code below:

```
varList = [ ['table1', 'col1', 'col2'],
        ['table1', 'col3', 'col4'],
        ['table2', 'col1', 'col2'],
        # ..
        # and many more such lines
        # ..
        ['table2', 'col3', 'col4']]

try:

    conn = psycopg2.connect(database='somename', user='someuser', password='somepasswd')

    c = conn.cursor()

    for listVar in varList:
        c.execute("SELECT %s FROM %s" %(listVar[1], listVar[0]))

        rowsList1 = c.fetchall();

        c.execute("SELECT %s FROM %s" %(listVar[2], listVar[0]))

        rowsList2 = c.fetchall();

        outfile = file('%s__%s' %(listVar[1], listVar[2]), 'w')

        for i in range(0, len(rowsList1)):
            if rowsList1[i][0] == None or rowsList2[i][0] == None:
                timeDiff = -1

            else:
                timestamp1 = time.mktime(rowsList1[i][0].timetuple())
                timestamp2 = time.mktime(rowsList2[i][0].timetuple())
                timeDiff = timestamp2 - timestamp1

            outfile.write(str(timeDiff) + '\n')

        outfile.close();

    del rowsList1, rowsList2

#numpy.savetxt('output.dat', column_stack(rows))

except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
    print 'Error %s' % e
    sys.exit(1)

finally:
    if conn:
        conn.close()
```

My initial guess was that there was some form of memory leak and in an attempt to fix this, I added a del statement on the two large arrays hoping that the memory gets properly collected. This time, I got slightly better outputs(by slightly better I mean that more output files were created for the db column pairs). 
However, after the 10th or 11th pair of columns, my program was "Killed" again. Can someone tell me what could be wrong here. Is there a better way of getting this done?
Any help is appreciated.

PS: I know that this is a fairly inefficient implementation as I'm looping many times, but I needed something quick and dirty for proof of concept.

Comment: How much data do you expect to process here?

Comment: cursor.fetchall() is probably the killer as it is going to try to duplicate your entire DB in core. fetchone() is probably what you want since you are processing it a row at a time anyway.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just get the database to calculate your time differences in SQL?  Then you could just iterate over the cursor and write out the values to the output file.

Comment: @GregHewgill: The database tables have around 250000-260000 rows. I'm trying to fetch all of these at once.

Comment: @msw: I'll be changing the code to use numpy or something similar to work with the entire list at once. So I would need something like fetchall() in the long run. Is there a less expensive alternative to this?

Comment: @JamesHenstridge: I need to perform a few operations on the columns before I calculate the difference. For ex: one of the pairs indicate time and they're in different formats. I need to bring them to one format(or convert to unix timestamp) and then find the difference. Can something like this be done using SQL?

Comment: Given you're using PostgreSQL, you've got a fair number of options.  You can do your conditional expressions with `CASE` or possibly `COALESCE`.  You can convert date/time types to unix timestamps with `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is you are selecting everything and then filtering it in the application code when you should be selecting what you want with the sql query.  If you select what you want in the sql query like this:

for listvar in varlist:
    select listvar[1], listvar[2] from listvar[0] where listvar[1] is not null and listvar[2] is not null

```
# then...

timeDiff = {}
for row in rows:
    timestamp1 = time.mktime(row[0].timetuple())
    timestamp2 = time.mktime(row[0].timetuple())
    timeDiff[identifier] = timestamp2 - timestamp1 #still need to assoc timediff with row... maybe you need to query a unique identifyer also?

#and possibly a separate... (this may not be necessary depending on your application code.  do you really need -1's for irrelevant data or can you just return the important data?)

select listvar[1], listvar[2] from listvar[0] where listvar[1] is null or listvar[2] is null

for row in rows:
    timeDiff[identifier] = -1 # or None
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't see how selecting both columns 1 and 2 in one go improves the situation as opposed to selecting them separately. Can you please throw some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: Good question.  This allows the database engine to do the work of filtering the data.  Using a cursor means that you will not get columns 1 and 2 all in one go, instead you will get only the subset of columns that have been pre-filtered by the database engine that meets your criteria.  Database engines are generally much more efficient at sorting and filtering data than client side code.

Comment: Also, you the two c.fetchall() lines are essentially doubling the amount of memory required to handle processing the data.  @msw pointed out the problem with fetchall() in his comment.  Using fetchall() essentially negates the benefit of using cursors.